# Adobe Flash Professional -- Can animated .gif export rendered animation within symbols?

Tags: flash, flash-cc

I'm currently using the 30-day free trial of Adobe Flash Professional CC. I was really pleased to see how easily you could export animations in animated .gif format, seemed to run without a hitch.

One thing I noticed while using Flash is that instances of symbols placed into a scene don't actually animate when you use the "Play" function -- that is to say, when you press Enter and the playhead starts moving along the timeline from its current position. They remain at the very first frame of their respective animations. In order to show the proper animations of symbols, you have to use the Test function (CTRL - Enter) to actually compile a working .swf of the thing.

This wasn't much of an issue until I tried to export in .gif format and I got this same issue. Instances of symbols don't animate, they only seem to work in compiled .swf's.

Since the use of symbols in the Flash workflow seems to be a rather common occurrence it seems unthinkable that Flash wouldn't support their usage with whatever mechanism they use to export animated .gif's. Is there some sort of silly mistake I'm making or checkbox I need to toggle? Or is the functionality honestly not there?

FileDropper link to the working file I'm using: http://www.filedropper.com/flashbottle

Answer (score 0):

Use the File->Export->Export Video... command, it will invoke the flash player in headless mode and capture the playback result losslessly. You will then have to convert it to your desired format, since this command only supports quicktime movies for the output format.